# Prove $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0 $ $\rightarrow$ $f\equiv c$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-topology

for $f:\Bbb{R^2}\to\Bbb{R}, f\in C^1  $ and $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0 $  for every $(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}$ then $f\equiv c\in\Bbb{R}$

I was thinking it's similar to $g:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ if $g'=0$ then $g\equiv c$ but I don't sure how to prove it. 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exactly correct in thinking it's similar to the 1D case. Possibly putting things into terms that you have learned:

$$0 = x \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ y \cfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = (x,y) \cdot \nabla f$$

You may have seen this as the definition of the directional derivative of f in $(x,y)$ direction: $D(f; (x,y))$. At this point, the formal way to prove what you're looking for would be to take the line integral of both sides along the straight vector $(x,y)$ as Omnom initially suggested. The fundamental theorem of calculus will tell you that $\int \nabla f \cdot ds = f|_{start}^{end}$.

However, it might be easier to grasp what's happening here if you think of this relation solely in terms of derivatives (or change). If the directional derivative of $f$ is 0 in every direction $(x,y)$, that means that $f$ does not change in any direction. This can only be true if your function $f$ is identically a constant in every direction. Therefore, your function $f$ is identically a constant.

Comment: thx, in this equation $\int \nabla f \cdot ds = f|_{start}^{end}$ what are the 'end' and 'start'?

Comment: @shay just as in 1D calculus: they are the limits of your integration. In your case they are the endpoints of a line segment starting at $(0,0)$ and going to $(x,y)$.

Comment: so I can claim that for any $(a,b),(c,d) \in \Bbb{R^2}$ $f(a,b)-f(c,d)=0$ $\rightarrow$ $f(a,b)=f(c,d) \equiv Y \in \Bbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Be careful: I think the statement "the directional derivative of $f$ is $0$ in every direction $(x,y)$" is misleading. At any given point $(x,y)$ other than  the origin, we only know that the directional derivative of $f$ is zero in the direction pointing _radially outward_ from $(x,y)$. If we didn't also know that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, this would not be enough to conclude that $f$ was constant.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** we may evaluate
$$
f(x,y) - f(0,0) = \int_c \nabla f(\vec s)\cdot d \vec s
$$
where $c$ is the radial line given by
$$
c(t) = (tx,ty) \quad t \in [0,1]
$$

---

**Alternative:** Apply the mean value theorem to the function
$$
g(t) = f(tx,ty) \quad t \in [0,1]
$$

Comment: sorry but we didn't learn it.

Comment: See my latest edit